# Поддержка uinput разными ОС

Tags: ос

Какие ОС кроме linux поддерживают uinput? Поиск адекватной информации не даёт.

Comment: мое гугление говорит, что только линукс и поддерживает. Это, если правильно понимаю, просто модуль к ядру с оберткой.

Comment: @KoVadim в сорцах freebsd есть что-то подобное ещё

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`uinput` - модуль ядра `Linux`, который начал свое существование с версии ядра 2.6.0, определяемый как `"User level driver support"`. В данный момент в других ОС этого функционала нет.

Однако, если брать ту же `FreeBSD`, делаются определенные попытки реализовать, скажем так, "смежный функционал". [Вот пример](https://reviews.freebsd.org/D6998) расширения `evdev` для FreeBSD. И, тем не менее, это все же разные вещи.

Таким образом, однозначный ответ - только `Linux`. Но, как говорят, Linux - это не операционная система, а только ядро. Дистрибутивы Linux - обладают свойствами "операционной системы". Так же и в `Android` (как в Linux-based ОС) - [есть поддержка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920561/how-to-enable-dev-input-uinput).

Comment: Мне казалось, что это "User level Input/Output subsystem"

Comment: Судя по соответствующему разделу конфига - http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/INPUT_UINPUT.html - называют "User level driver support"

Comment: Хотя, я не вижу вущественной разницы - главное "модуль ядра Линукс", а это многое объясняет.